# Python: cannot import librosa library --> OSError: cannot load library 'libsndfile.so' :

Tags: python, installation, pip, librosa

I am running my python code on the cloud using paperspace gradient.  My code utilizes the librosa library.  It was all working fine just a couple weeks ago meaning the entire codebase runs without error.

But today it seems like there's something wrong with librosa.  When I try to do "import librosa" I get the following error:

**OSError: cannot load library 'libsndfile.so': libsndfile.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I don't know what this means or how to rectify it.  I have tried updating both my pip and my wheel.  I have also tried pip installing soundfile as well.  But the error remains.

Comment: https://github.com/librosa/librosa#soundfile

Answer (score 2):

Please check the librosa [dependencies](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/install.html)

Need **ffmpeg** for decoding sound files

May need **soundfile** [library](https://github.com/librosa/librosa#soundfile)

In my case there was no libsndfile1

I resolved using: `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1`
Blog to install [libsndfile1](https://howtoinstall.co/en/libsndfile1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34682546)